# Force directed graph drawn out of the allocated SVG size

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, force-layout

I'm trying to create force directed graph like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). It drew just fine when I was using the sample data. But when I use my own data, the nodes seem to be drawn out of the svg size. 
Here is what I get:
[image]

And here is my code:

```
var nodes = createFDGNodes(stopsByLine);
var links = createFDGLinks(stopsByLine);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                    .force("link", d3.forceLink()
                        .id(function(d) { return d.id; })
                    )
                    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody()
                        .distanceMin(function(d) {return 1; })
                    )
                    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(960/2, 500/2));

const circleGroup = d3.select("div.transit-network")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", 960)
                    .attr("height", 500)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class","fdg");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var link = circleGroup.append("g")
            .attr("class", "links")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(links)
            .enter().append("line")
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", 1);

var node = circleGroup.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("r", 5)
                .attr("class", function(d) {return "line-"+d.lineId+" stop-"+d.id;})
                .attr("fill", function(d){
                    return color(d.lineId);
                });

simulation.nodes(nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

simulation.force("link")
    .links(links);

function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}
```

How could I make the graph so it is drawn within the allocated svg size?

Comment: use a viewBox appropriate to your data set

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way to make your simulation fitting inside your allocated area is tweaking all the forces in the simulation, like `forceManyBody`, `forceLink`, `forceCenter` etc...

However, you can *force* the simulation (no pun intended) to fit in a given area. For instance, in the following demo, the simulation will be constrained in a small area of 100 x 100 pixels using this inside the `tick` function:

```
node.attr("transform", (d) => {
    return "translate(" + (d.x < 10 ? dx = 10 : d.x > 90 ? d.x = 90 : d.x) +
        "," + (d.y < 10 ? d.y = 10 : d.y > 90 ? d.y = 90 : d.y) + ")"
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var width = 100;
var height = 100;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var nodes = [{
  "id": "foo"
}, {
  "id": "bar"
}, {
  "id": "baz"
}, {
  "id": "foobar"
}];

var edges = [{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 1
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 2
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 3
}];

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1000))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var links = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(edges)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("stroke-width", 1);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var node = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g");

var nodeCircle = node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("stroke", "gray")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("fill", "white");

simulation.nodes(nodes);
simulation.force("link")
  .links(edges);

simulation.on("tick", function() {

  node.attr("transform", (d) => {
    return "translate(" + (d.x < 10 ? dx = 10 : d.x > 90 ? d.x = 90 : d.x) + "," + (d.y < 10 ? d.y = 10 : d.y > 90 ? d.y = 90 : d.y) + ")"
  })

  links.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })


});
```

```css
svg{
   background-color: lemonchiffon;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mike Bostock's [Bounded force layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492) also works and you can set the radius to match your nodes.

`node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)); });`

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak with .strength function; e.g.

```
         .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5) )
```